# sql cascading deletes

Tags: sql, cascading-deletes

I have a question about cascading deletes and foreign key references:
Let's assume the following tables:

```
ITEMX                 | ITEMY
------------------    | ------------
ID    FKID_ITEMY      | ID
1     1               | 1
2     1               |
```

There is a cascade delete on FKID_ITEMY such that if I delete a row in ITEMX, the corresponding item in ITEMY will be deleted. My question is:

Will the delete of row ID 1 in ITEMX delete row ID 1 in ITEMY?

Or will just delete row ID 1 in ITEMX because row ID 2 is still referencing row ID 1 in ITEMY?

In other words, I would like to see row ID 1 of ITEMY deleted when there are no more references to it. Will a cascade delete achieve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've got the concept of cascading deletes *backwards*.

Even though you declare FKID_ITEMY with a cascading delete option, nothing happens if you delete ITEMX where ID=1.

The cascading behavior affects what happens if the referenced row in ITEMY gets deleted.  If you delete ITEMY where ID=1, it will delete both rows in ITEMX that reference that row.

You declare the cascading behavior on the foreign key in a dependent table, because you could have another dependent table ITEMZ, and you want it to behave differently.  E.g. if you try to delete a row in ITEMY then you want that to be cancelled if there exist any referencing rows in ITEMZ.

Comment: That's what I thought, but it's nice to have it confirmed. The model we have is a little kooky, but we've had to make it that way for business reasons. I'll instead put the cascade on the foreign key relationship and set FKID_ITEMY to a known default in ITEMY.

Thank you!